# C++ networking, recv() fails for no reason (?)

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, recv

I'm writing a chat server in c++ for my own amusement, but I'm fairly new to networking in general. My knowledge comes from Beej's guide, [this site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/), and the Top Down approach from Kurose&Ross.

My problem is, that I wrote code veeery similar to the one you can find at the link, but it's not working. The program fails when I try to use the recv() function on the server.

I know recv() can return any number of bytes, but it simply gives me -1. I know I need a loop to piece together the message being sent, but there isn't anything like that just yet. The send() in the client however, says it sent the amount specified in the buffer (yes I know it's probably overkill, not sure if that's a mistake though).

To me it looks like the server is ... closed off somehow ? I'm pretty sure I messed up somewhere, there's a certain line of code I'm really not sure about (look for the comment). I managed to get it work yesterday but something went wrong after that.

I'm really new to socket programming and any kind of networking in general, but the function calls and whatnot came from guides, I have a hunch the problem will be at the part where I specify the ports and addresses, maybe the bytes don't arrive at the server because I'm sending them somewhere else? But if the accept() works, doesn't that mean that a TCP connection is formed, shouldn't i be able to use it after that ?

I'm using Lubuntu linux, the latest release, if that helps.

If you find the problem, can you please tell me how to do it correctly ? Anyways, here's the server's code:

```
void start() {

    char message[1024] = "";

    int socketfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 ), opt = 1, new_socket;

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    struct sockaddr_storage cl_addr;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(address);

    if( socketfd != 0 ) {

        address.sin_family = AF_INET;
        address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
        address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        if( setsockopt(socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(int)) < 0 ) {
            perror("Setsockopt failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if( bind( socketfd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, len ) < 0 ) {           
            perror("Couldn't bind to port");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } 

        if( listen( socketfd, 3 ) < 0 ) {
            perror("Listening on port failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if( (new_socket = accept( socketfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cl_addr, (socklen_t*)&len  ) < 0) ) {
            perror("Couldn't accept request");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /// This is where it fails
        std::cout << recv( new_socket, message, 1024, 0) <<  std::endl;
        close(new_socket);
    }
    else {
        perror("Couldn't open socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close( socketfd );
}
```

And now the client:

```
int main(void) {

int sockfd;

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
char hello[1024] = "Hello";

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

/// I'm not sure about this !! 
inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr);

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if( sockfd == 0 ) {
    perror("Opening socket failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) != -1 ) {
    /// Says it sent 1024, but sever doesn't recieve it, what gives ?
    int test = send( sockfd, hello, sizeof(hello), 0);
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
}
else {
    perror("Error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

As you can see, it's similar to the code found at the link. The server code is just a function, there are other parts of the code like creating user files, but none of them are being used in the networking part, so I didn't feel like posting another 800 lines of code for nothing. The main() of the server is just me creating an object of the server class and calling start() on it.

I'd like to improve where I can, so if you notice something I can do better, please tell me, be it general coding style or anything. Also, It's my first question here ever, and my first language isn't english, please go easy on me :)

Comment: When  you get a `-1` return code, you can print out the error message using `std::cerr << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';` That may give you some insight.

Comment: `sockaddr` structures may be used partially initialized here. You should zero them prior to filling. `if( socketfd != 0 )` is not correct as well because invalid socket value will be -1.

Comment: You obviously read the documentation for `recv()` which says that -1 gets returned when an error occurs, because your code diligently checks for it. However, that documentation also says that `errno` gets set to indicate the reason for the error.

Comment: Thank you! I'll be back with the error message

@VTT - will something like memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); work ? I copied this from the example code and wasn't sure why he did this.

Comment: In modern `C++`, zero-initialization, usually of the form "object={}", has the effect of initializing the object to all zeroes, without having to devolve to prehistoric C-style structure clearing code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - thank you, I was afraid I'll need to use something new again.

The error returned "Socket operation on non-socket" which is ... interesting ?

Comment: Not sure why you deleted the post, because I was about to tell you the issue.  The `accept` statement in your server program has a parentheses problem.  `new_socket` is getting assigned `0`.

Comment: @selbie Did I delete it ? If you mean the comment, I might have edited it like 4 times trying to write a dot between two words ... anyways THANK YOU ! If you hadn't told me I would've spent DAYS trying to figure it out, it's working now ! How do I mark your comment as an answer ? Newer mind I got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a parentheses problem.

This line:

```
if( (new_socket = accept( socketfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cl_addr, (socklen_t*)&len  ) < 0) ) {
```

`<` operator has a higher evaluation precedence than the `=` operator.

`new_socket` is getting assigned the evaluation of `accept() < 0`, which is a false expression, so `new_socket` gets assigned zero.

This is probably what you meant:

```
if (new_socket = accept( socketfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cl_addr, (socklen_t*)&len ) < 0)
```

But this is far less error prone:

```
new_socket = accept( socketfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cl_addr, (socklen_t*)&len  ); 
if (new_socket < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't accept request");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Example 1,152,815,975,467 of why stuffing an assignment statement into an `if` or `while` conditional clause is almost always a really bad idea.  **Saving lines of code is a useless goal**.

Comment: Truer words have never been spoken Andrew. These bugs are incredibly difficult to spot.

Comment: Thank you, and you're right,  this is just something my teacher at college made me do.  "Do it like this" he said, "It's more readable", he said ... sure ...

Comment: @AndrewHenle - at least these days (C++17) we can do [if (initialization; condition)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r1.html).

Comment: @ZomborMate No, it's not "more readable".  And such code also pretty much precludes robust error handling where you might want to handle different types of failures differently.  For example, a call such as `msgrcv()` that will never be automatically restarted if it's interrupted, so you have to loop and check `errno` for `EINTR` so you can retry - while also handling all other non-interrupt errors.  Why do I suspect your teacher has never been subject to getting called in at 2 AM should his code not handle an error robustly?

Comment: (cont) It's really pretty simple:  the human mind can only accurately track a handful of things at one time - three to seven are normally the accepted range.  When you start putting 4, or 5, or 6 or more things going on in a single line of code it gets very hard to grasp the entirety of what's happening.  Throw in the arcane rules of C operator precedence to an `if` condition with 4 or 5 operations happening, and now your already-almost-maxed-out-brain has to track the relationships **between** those operations.

Comment: (cont) Decades of peer-reviewed research says anyone claiming they can understand all that code stuffed into one line is a liar.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, he thinks he knows his shit, but he's kind of a doofus ... I understand why doing it is bad, and I hate it as well, but after being forced to do something in one way, it's really hard to stop ... anyways, after this I'll be on the watch :)